# Unable to select an option from a dropdown using Python, Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to use the below code to use selenium (python) to select an option from a dropdown on a webpage.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

import time
import os
import wget

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.hkbea.com/jsp/hk/bea-mpf-fund-information2.jsp?language=en')

#select scheme dropdown menu
scheme_name = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("mpfGroup"))
scheme_name.select_by_visible_text('BEA (MPF) Master Trust Scheme')

#select fund dropdown menu
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-id="mpfFunds"]'))).click()
funds = Select(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'mpfFunds')))).options
funds.select_by_value("AGF")
#funds.select_by_visible_text("BEA (MPF) Asian Equity Fund")
```

It is fine to select the scheme dropdown menu(1st one), but the problem comes when I try to select fund dropdown menu(2nd one).

```
# without select
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-id="mpfFunds"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul[data-original-index="0"]'))).click()
```

I try to used another way without using select class, it only works for `'ul[data-original-index="0"]'` element, but not for the others like `'ul[data-original-index="1"]'`..

I would appreciate any feedback on how to consistently select an option from the dropdown noted in the code provided. And here is the website I looking at: https://www.hkbea.com/jsp/hk/bea-mpf-fund-information2.jsp?language=en

Comment: second dropdown menu depend on the first dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the drop down are not made of Select and option so you can not use Select from Selenium, they are made of li and span try below code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.hkbea.com/jsp/hk/bea-mpf-fund-information2.jsp?language=en")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
#click on accept cookie button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.accept-span"))).click()

#Scheme name drop down
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Please select scheme']/.."))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='BEA (MPF) Master Trust Scheme']/.."))).click()

#Constituent Funds: drop down

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Please select constituent fund']/.."))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='BEA (MPF) Asian Equity Fund']/.."))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[image]

**Update 1 :**

You can not select more than 3 options at a time, that's your application issue. However, the below code should click on all the options but would only select 3, since Application does not allow.

```
#Constituent Funds: drop down
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Please select constituent fund']/.."))).click()
total_number_of_options = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@data-original-index]/a[@class='opt MT ']"))
i = 1
while total_number_of_options > 0 :
    try:
        ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"(//li[@data-original-index]/a[@class='opt MT '])[{i}]")))
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele).click().perform()
        time.sleep(1)
        i = i + 1
    except:
        print('click did not work')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, it is doable, but I need to use for loop to select all the funds one by one. That's why I can't use XPATH. Is there any solution eg get element by css selector `li[data-original-index="1"]`. I've tried using it and it still got the same problem: only work for `li[data-original-index="0"]`..

Comment: @tericiu : try out the update 1 code above.

Comment: emm.. the update 1 seems cannot click one of them.

Comment: @tericiu : that's hard to digest, but it does work in my local. Are you aware that you could select only 3 option from 2nd drop down ? Web application does not allow to select more than 3 options at a time

Comment: Thank you so much! actually this XPATH:`f"(//li[@data-original-index]/a[@class='opt MT '])[{i}]"` works.